# Implicit ClassTag in pattern matching

Tags: scala, reflection

Let's take this for an example:

```
import scala.reflect._

def get[T](list: List[Any])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = {
  list.flatMap {
    case element: T => Some(element)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

I can use `get()` to get values of type `T` from a list (e.g. `get[String](list)` will give me all strings from that list).

Now, I understand that compiler provides the value of type `ClassTag[String]` automatically. I also understand that `ClassTag` is a type class, and somewhere behind the curtain there's a piece of code that says `implicitly[ClassTag[T]].getRuntimeClass()` or whatever.

But if that's so, how come we can pattern match without the class tag (we just can't differentiate between erased types in that case)? I mean, how is it achieved that, if I declare an implicit parameter (which is automatically provided by the compiler), I get one behavior, but if i don't I get a different behavior?

Comment: Just on a side note, you can make this code more concise like this `def get[T : ClassTag](list: List[Any]) = list collect { case element: T => element }`

Comment: Yeah I know, this way it's even more obvious that `tag` is not used within the method. It just seems a bit magical that there's a possibility to add an implicit parameter and not do anything explicitly with it, and yet get a different behavior than when the parameter is not there.

Comment: Yes, I do understand your question, I find it interesting myself, I upvoted it and I'm waiting for an answer, but I'm guessing compiler is doing something here.

Comment: [Documentation](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html) just states that if you declare an implicit parameter of type `ClassTag` (same goes for (Weak)TypeTags) compiler will provide one for you. But nothing about what's going on once you're inside the method and may or may not have an implicit value of type ClassTag at disposal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler automatically translates your code roughly to this:

```
  def get[T](list: List[Any])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = list.flatMap {
    case (element @ tag(_: T)) => Some(element)
    case _ => None
  }
```

`ClassTag` has an `unapply(x: Any)` overload that allows it to pattern match on values. I've cleaned up the tree obtained from `reify` to only show the relevant parts, but this will show you the full tree:

```
scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify { 
    def get[T](list: List[Any])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = {
      list.flatMap {
        case element: T => Some(element)
        case _ => None
      }
    }
}
```

Also see the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag@unapply(x:Any):Option[T]):

> The compiler tries to turn unchecked type tests in pattern matches into checked ones by wrapping a `(_: T)` type pattern as `ct(_: T)`, where `ct` is the `ClassTag[T]` instance. Type tests necessary before calling other extractors are treated similarly. `SomeExtractor(...)` is turned into `ct(SomeExtractor(...))` if `T` in `SomeExtractor.unapply(x: T)` is uncheckable, but we have an instance of `ClassTag[T]`.

Comment: And if I don't have the implicit parameter?

Comment: Then it has no `ClassTag` to use as an extractor, so it'll suffer from type erasure on `T`.