# Scala polymorphic methods - { case x:T => x } returns all types

Tags: scala, methods, polymorphism

I do not understand why in Scala polymorphic method do not work as I expected.

lets have method:

```
def sth[T](list: Iterable[Any]): List[T] = {
list.collect({case s:T => s}).toList
}
```

not I would like to get only Boolean from my list. so I would write:

```
val out = sth[Boolean](List(true, false, 2.0, 2, 4, 12.3))
```

What I expect is `List(true, false)` and IntelIJ shows me that `out` is instance of: `List[Boolean]` BUT what this method returns me is my input list: `List(true, false, 2.0, 2, 4, 12.3)`

I also did try with `list.filter(s => s.isInstanceOf[T])` but had same result.

[image]

I'm a little bit confused. Can u explain me what have I done wrong?

Comment: Note, additionally to the excellent Mario's answer. You must know that having **Any** is a code smell. You should never end up in that situation. If you do, you probably need to refactor something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to *type erasure* the check

```
case s:T => ...
```

becomes something like

```
if (s.isInstanceOf[Object]) ...
```

as indicated by the compiler warning message

```
 warning: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    list.collect({case s:T => s}).toList
```

Try providing [ClassTag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572269/5205022) like so

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def collect[T: ClassTag](list: Iterable[Any]): List[T] = {
  list.collect({ case s: T => s }).toList
}

collect[Boolean](List(true, false, 2.0, 2, 4, 12.3))
collect[Double](List(true, false, 2.0, 2, 4, 12.3))
```

which outputs

```
res0: List[Boolean] = List(true, false)
res1: List[Double] = List(2.0, 12.3)
```

which works due to some compiler magic explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36875128/5205022).

Here is our own type class solution

```
trait Collectable[T] {
  def collect(list: Iterable[Any]): List[T]
}

object Collectable {
  def collect[T](list: Iterable[Any])(implicit ev: Collectable[T]): List[T] =
    ev.collect(list)

  implicit val booleanCollect: Collectable[Boolean]  = 
    (list: Iterable[Any]) => list.collect({ case s: Boolean => s }).toList

  implicit val doubleCollect: Collectable[Double] = 
    (list: Iterable[Any]) => list.collect({ case s: Double => s }).toList
}

import Collectable._

collect[Boolean](List(true, false, 2.0, 2, 4, 12.3))
collect[Double](List(true, false, 2.0, 2, 4, 12.3))
```

which outputs

```
res0: List[Boolean] = List(true, false)
res1: List[Double] = List(2.0, 12.3)
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains why it matches everything (in Scala we all are Objects). Still it is weird for me that I got typed List[Boolean] with Doubles and Int's in it.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, I have some material to study now :)

Comment: Note that the moment you want to `collect` more complex types, this is insufficient. Example create a **List[List[Any]]** and try to filter of it, only the inner **List[Int]** you will see that it will collect all lists no matter if they contain other types like **String** inside.