# Why the Scala method isInstanceOf[T] is not working

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, instanceof, type-erasure

**Why the `isInstanceOf[T]` method is not working as intended?**

In the following, I have defined a `hello` class and companion object. In the hello object, I test `this.isInstanceOf[T]` in the line of codes " `hel.typetest[Int]` ", how come this is `true` when the type `T` is `Int`?

```
object hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Console.println("main")
    val hel = new hello
    hel.typetest[Int]
  }
}

class hello {
  def typetest[T: ClassTag]: Unit = {
    Console.println(this.isInstanceOf[T])
    Console.println(this.getClass)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
main
true
class hello
```

Comment: Using `isInstanceOf` commonly is bad style. It can't check generics types (and then most of collections). Doc: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Any.html#isInstanceOf[T0]:Boolean

Answer (score 8):

Because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) (together with boxing). `T` erases to `Object`, so `this.isInstanceOf[T]` becomes `this.isInstanceOf[Object]` in bytecode which is always true.

As it happens, `ClassTag` is intended to avoid this, but you need to actually use it instead of calling `isInstanceOf`:

```
def typetest[T](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Unit = {
  Console.println(tag.runtimeClass.isInstance(this))
}
```

There's also special-case [support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36875128/5205022) for pattern-matching against `T` when a `ClassTag` is present:

```
def typetest[T: ClassTag]: Unit = {
  Console.println(this match {
    case _: T => true
    case _ => false
  })
}
```

There were proposals to make `is`/`asInstanceOf[T]` work correctly when a `ClassTag` is present too, but there are assumptions built into the compiler which prevent this and would be too hard to change (if I remember the reason correctly).

Comment: Just to add: ClassTag only matches higher type. It does not match for argument type of higher type. For example:  
`valueToMatch match {
  case _: T => true  
  case _ => false`  
if valueToMatch is a List[Int], it will always print true if T is a List irrespective of  whether T is List[String] or List[Int] or any other type of List.

Answer (score 0):

After searching lots of posts and fighting the type erasure warning, I came across this stack overflow answer [Implicit ClassTag in pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874755/implicit-classtag-in-pattern-matching/36875128#36875128)

Based on that post, I created the following implicit type matcher to check if an object is or is not an instance of the generic type T. Hope this helps someone.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object ObjectExtensions {
  implicit class IsType(obj: Object) {
    def isType[T](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Boolean = obj match {
      case tag(_: T) => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

** edited: After more investigation, instead of using isInstanceOf[T] you need to use classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(objectToCheck) as noted by Alexey Romanov's answer.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object ObjectExtensions {
  implicit class IsType(obj: Object) {
    def isType[T : ClassTag](): Boolean = {
      classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(obj)
    }
  }
}
```